# why partial rendering doesn't work on mobile device?

Tags: iphone, firefox, mobile, rendering, partial

in order to improve latency, I'm doing an experiment to emit html content piece by piece instead of waiting for the whole page gets ready, the idea is, whenever a part of the whole page is ready, then emit it immediately, so client can show this part first. it works fine on all main PC browsers, like FireFox, Chrome, IE and Opera, but on mobile device, this doesn't work, seems the mobile browsers wait for the whole content of the page ready then render it as a whole. what I tested: iPhone, Andriod and BlackBerry.

does anybody have any experience / idea about this? what specialty of mobile devices could possibly cause this difference?

any reply would greatly appreciated.